# How can I unpack and decompile a VMP protected exe?

Tags: exe, unpack

I have a VMP protected exe file, the app is a very simple console application with some injection processes, written in CPP. I want to decompile it, because the app is discontinued but useful, and i want to update it, fix the bugs, and so on. If i have the cpp code i can go from there with it, but i dont know how can i unpack and decompile a VMP protected exe. I tried to do it based of yt videos, and i searched it up, but i dont really find anything useful or working. Can somebody help me with it? (I wanna learn the method and the things behind it, i dont wanna you to do the work.)

Answer (score 0):

for first if u need to unpack vmp pe file, u need to find OEP to rebuild IAT (Import Address Table) to find places where functions from other libraries has called (import functions for example). After that u need to dump file with fixed IAT and analyze file in IDA.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).